# Remove all trailing decimal points from a number stored as a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim, charindex

I have a couple of strings (`nvarchar` data type), one is a whole number and one has decimal points trailing. My goal is to remove decimals and have all values as a whole number.

I tried the code below but it gives me an error for the value with no decimals. Is there a way to accomplish this without a case expression. I'll be using this new column in a join.

```
SELECT [SOW]
  --,LEFT([SOW], CHARINDEX('.', [SOW])-1) as 'TestColumn'
FROM [dbo].[t_Schedule_kdm]
WHERE sow  in ('15229.11','11092')

Output:
11092
15229.11

My desired Output:
11092
15229
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Would it be tacky to just cast it to an integer?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*. And why would you want to avoid it? Its very useful for situations like this.

Comment: @TimRoberts , I tried: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '15229.11' to data type int.

Comment: SELECT CAST(CAST([SOW] AS REAL) AS INT) will work ... as long as all your values are numbers in good format. For instance, '1' will work and so will '1.1111' but '1,111.11' will not work because the CAST does not understand thousands separators.

Comment: Except you don't want to use `real` - thats only intended for scientific numbers, and can cause errors for regular decimals.

Comment: And should it always truncate? Or should it round?

Comment: always truncate, I just wanted to strip all following the dot as I wanted whole numbers only. Hence, using that field to join table that has only whole numbers.

Comment: Try this before you use that cast to real: `SELECT CAST(CAST('99999.999' AS REAL) AS INT)`

Answer (score 1):

Just append a dot character so that you'll always find an index:

```
LEFT(SOW, CHARINDEX('.', SOW + '.') - 1)
```

It's not clear whether you need to cast the result of that expression to an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Convert first to the most precision number you could ever have e.g. `decimal(9,2)` then convert to an `int`. You can't convert directly from a decimal string to an int.

```
SELECT [Value]
  , CONVERT(int,CONVERT(decimal(9,2),[Value]))
FROM (
    VALUES ('15229.11'),('11092')
) x ([Value]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work if you have something like `.999`.

Comment: @shawnt00 yip - as I said "Convert first to the most precision number you could ever have" so if OP can have more precision they just add more precision.

Comment: Admittedly I glossed over that first sentence. The reasoning behind that it probably not apparent to OP though.